# Running create database and drop database command in Oracle SQL developer using MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I am newbie to MySQL and Oracle. I have installed Oracle SQL developer and using MySQL.
I tried run these commands one by one and the result was OK.

```
show databases;
create database practice;
use practice;
create table practice(practice varchar(30));
desc practice;
drop table practice;
drop database practice;
show databases;
```

But when I ran them as a script....database was not getting dropped...Can anyone explain if something is wrong in script or otherwise..

Comment: Who or what is running the script. What are its privileges?

Comment: i ran these commands as a group and not one by one in Oracle SQL Developer...user has DB Admin privileges